# Does anyone know what this sans-serif font is? (EAGO)

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

I'm trying to find this font - have wasted a few hours now - and any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have a collection of font identification resources, and it is a good idea to try that first. Edit your question and let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increases. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Answer (score 1):

The main interest in this logo represents letter "G".

Probably, this letter creation was inspired by letter "G"  designed by [George Braisher in 1961](http://www.thesportsdesignblog.com/2012/01/18/the-history-of-the-packers-g/) for [Packers](http://www.packers.com/) (their site' favicon is actually represented by  this letter):

[image]

Almost the same lettering share Logo of football [team](http://hbcubuzz.com/grambling-state-reassigns-both-basketball-coaches/) of Grambling University -

[image]

Probably because of [lettering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_lettering) this letter G is not a part of any popular font, thus the letters in question were probably created by lettering as well.

Comment: Many thanks - very interesting! :) I spent hours searching through font sites - now I know why. :)

Comment: @Alice you are invited to upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is custom-made. I downloaded their [brochure](http://issuu.com/eagoukltd/docs/brochure__web_) and everything except the logo was in [Lucida Grande](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucida_Grande).